# Configuring connection pooling in Cassandra using C++ driver

Tags: c++, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Although connection pooling has been mentioned as one of the features of the Cassandra's C++ driver(https://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/), no details have been given regarding its implementation in C++.
Can anybody help regarding the configuration of connection pools in the C++ program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For high-level description of what connection pooling is, you can use documentation from [Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/pooling/) (unfortunately there is no corresponding documentation for C++ driver).

C++ driver also have slightly different configuration options - for example, there is only one configuration for number of connections, while Java driver allows to specify different numbers for local & remote clusters.

You can use function `cass_cluster_set_core_connections_per_host` to specify a minimal number of network connections to host, and `cass_cluster_set_max_connections_per_host` to specify maximal number of connections to host - driver will resize pool if necessary. And function `cass_cluster_set_max_concurrent_requests_threshold` specifies how many requests could be in-flight for one network connection.  You can look to [tests of C++ driver](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/test/integration_tests/src/test_pool.cpp#L60) for examples.

But be very careful with changing these settings, as this may lead to increased resource consumption.

Comment: what is the maximum value that i can set for cass_cluster_set_max_concurrent_requests_threshold ?

Comment: I don't remember precisely, but something like 100? You need to check source code